# Linear Diophantine Equation vs linear congruence

Tags: diophantine-equations

I just saw the next two theorems and I asked myself some questions about it.

**Linear Diophantine Equation:**

Let a and b be integers with $d=(a,b)$. The equation $ax+by=c$ has:

1) No integral solutions if $c$ is not divisible by $d$

2) Infinity many integral solutions if $c$ is divisible by $d$

*The solutions are given by:*
$x=x_0 + \frac{b}{d}n, y=y_0+\frac{a}{d}n$

**Linear congruences:**

Let a, b and m be integers with $d=(a,m)$. The congruence $ax\equiv b(\mod m)$ has:

1) No solutions if $c$ is not divisible by $d$

2) d incongruent solutions if $c$ is divisible by $d$

*The solutions are given by:*
$x=x_0 + \frac{m}{d}t, y=y_0+\frac{a}{d}t$

The linear congruence $ax\equiv b(modm)$ is equivalent to $ax-my=b$.

**Question 1:**

1) Diophantine Equation: $ax+by=c$ and solution $x=x_0 + \frac{b}{d}n, y=y_0+\frac{a}{d}n$

2) Linear congruence: $ax-my=b$ and solution $x=x_0 + \frac{m}{d}t, y=y_0+\frac{a}{d}t$

The only thing that has changed in the solution (2) is that $b$ is replaced by an $m$, but why is that the only change? The $+b$ in $ax+by=c$ has also become an $-m$ in $ax-my=b$?

**Question 2:**

1) Diophantine Equation: **Infinity many** integral solutions if $c$ is divisible by $d$

2) Linear congruence: **d** incongruent solutions if $c$ is divisible by $d$

Why are there first infinity many solutions and in the second case only d?

Comment: Last line: there are not "only d solutions" in the second case. It rather says "$d$ *incongruent* solutions", so still infinitely many.

Comment: Also, in the first case also the value of $c$ is a multiple of $d$. That way speaking, there is only one value in the first case. Also, what matters is the form of the equation, names of variables are a way to handle only.

Comment: Both are linear equations with solution in parametric form.